# Robotium scroll to view

Tags: android, android-espresso, robotium

I can do this in Android Espresso:

```
onView(withId(R.id.footer)).perform(scrollTo());
```

While doing this, the test framework will scroll the screen onto the view (the view is on a scroll view).

But I couldn't find this basic function in [Robotium](http://recorder.robotium.com/javadoc/com/robotium/solo/Solo.html), I personally lot prefer Robotium over Espresso, but quite surprise they kind of do not have this function? Do I miss anything?

Comment: I am curious why you like Roboto better than Espresso?

Comment: I tried Espresso before, although it claim that espresso thread is always syn with the instrumentation thread, but don't know why I still can't get the test pass correctly, and it lack of documentation (and answer in stackoverflow) right now make it very hard to look for solutions. And in Robotium, it has `waitForCondition` which is very helpful to syn thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just found a simple way, instead of relying on Robotium `drag()` method, in the instrumentation test case, I can directly `getView` the `scrollview` and perform its original android function `scrollview.scrollTo(x,y)`, which is quite good enough to achieve my objective.

Example:

```
ScrollView verticalSv = (ScrollView) solo.getView(R.id.verticalScrollView);
verticalSv.scrollTo(0, 100);
```